# problem to compil code addr.cpp

Tags: bitcoin-core, libbitcoin

Trying to compile with `g++ -o addr addr.cpp -std=c++11 $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libbitcoin)` is getting me this error:

```
/home/user/myprefix/lib/libsecp256k1.a(libsecp256k1_la-secp256k1.o) : Dans la fonction « secp256k1_num_mod_inverse » :
/home/user/build-libbitcoin/secp256k1/src/num_gmp_impl.h:128 : référence indéfinie vers « __gmpn_gcdext »
/home/user/myprefix/lib/libsecp256k1.a(libsecp256k1_la-secp256k1.o) : Dans la fonction « __gmpn_sub » :
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gmp.h:2190 : référence indéfinie vers « __gmpn_sub_n »
/home/user/myprefix/lib/libsecp256k1.a(libsecp256k1_la-secp256k1.o) : Dans la fonction « secp256k1_num_set_bin » :
/home/user/build-libbitcoin/secp256k1/src/num_gmp_impl.h:49 : référence indéfinie vers « __gmpn_set_str »
/home/user/build-libbitcoin/secp256k1/src/num_gmp_impl.h:49 : référence indéfinie vers « __gmpn_set_str »
/home/user/myprefix/lib/libsecp256k1.a(libsecp256k1_la-secp256k1.o) : Dans la fonction « secp256k1_num_get_bin » :
/home/user/build-libbitcoin/secp256k1/src/num_gmp_impl.h:34 : référence indéfinie vers « __gmpn_get_str »
/home/user/myprefix/lib/libsecp256k1.a(libsecp256k1_la-secp256k1.o) : Dans la fonction « secp256k1_num_set_bin » :
/home/user/build-libbitcoin/secp256k1/src/num_gmp_impl.h:49 : référence indéfinie vers « __gmpn_set_str »
/home/user/build-libbitcoin/secp256k1/src/num_gmp_impl.h:49 : référence indéfinie vers « __gmpn_set_str »
/home/user/myprefix/lib/libsecp256k1.a(libsecp256k1_la-secp256k1.o) : Dans la fonction « secp256k1_num_get_bin » :
/home/user/build-libbitcoin/secp256k1/src/num_gmp_impl.h:34 : référence indéfinie vers « __gmpn_get_str »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: What are you trying to compile?

Comment: https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/code/addr.cpp

Comment: You should find where GMP object files are installed and add the compile flag `-l/path/to/gmp/lib`